# prime number finder error - displaying non primes as primes

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I've been working through the problems on project euler and instead of using bruteforce, I wanted to complete the problems with a quality solution. I built this to find prime numbers, and have been testing it for values. When I look for the 12th prime, it's telling me it's 35 (which it obviously is not).

It should be identifying 35 as not a prime number since all previous primes are added to a list, but something is going wrong here. Any ideas?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int nthTerm = 12;
    int count = 3;
    int nPrime = 3;
    ArrayList<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>();
    primeList.add(3);
    int upperBoundary;
    ArrayList<Integer> checkList = new ArrayList<>();
    int check;
    boolean isPrime;

    while (count < nthTerm) {
        isPrime = false;
        nPrime += 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < primeList.size(); i++){
            upperBoundary = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(nPrime));
            if (primeList.get(i) <= upperBoundary){
                checkList.add(primeList.get(i));
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < checkList.size(); j++){
            check = checkList.get(j);
            if (nPrime % check == 0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } else {
                isPrime = true;
                primeList.add(nPrime);
            }
        }

        if (isPrime == true) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Prime number " + count + ": " + nPrime);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to recalculate `upperBoundary` inside the first for loop. That value isn't changing on each iteration of that loop, so just calculate it in the while loop.

Second, for low values of `nPrime` you're not adding anything to your `checkList`. This is the root problem. The value 5 is never added to that list, so both 25 and 35 are identified as prime.

Last, you should debug your code by running it in a debugger, or at least printing out some values at intermediate steps. Looking at all of the values that are identified as prime by your algorithm and that are in your `checkList` variable should lead you to a solution.

(Also, it would help to explain your approach when posting questions here. It would be easier to understand where your code is going wrong if there was an explanation of what it's trying to do.)

Comment: Cheers! I'm still working on fixing the checkList issue, but that really helped. Apologies about the lack of comments. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nthTerm = 12;
    int nPrime = 3;
    List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>();
    primeList.add(2);
    primeList.add(3);

    while (primeList.size() < nthTerm) {
        nPrime += 2;

        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int primeIndex = 1; primeIndex < primeList.size(); primeIndex++) {
            int prime = primeList.get(primeIndex);
            if (nPrime % prime == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            primeList.add(nPrime);
            System.out.println("Prime number " + primeList.size() + ": " + nPrime);
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Prime number " + nthTerm + ": " + nPrime);

}
```

The problem with your code:

- you are adding non primes in the list for example 25. Just because 25 % 3 == 1 (adding in for if not multipple by a prime - not checking ALL)
- checklist never cleared - it can contain multiple elements like: 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, ...